# stylus/css import: select all but ones with a suffix

Tags: css, regex, import, stylus

A `.styl` file imports all files from selected folders. How to correctly write a rule (or, what is the best way) to import all files except ones that contain the `-ie` suffix (i.e. bar-ie.style)?

The following code is not wroking:

```
import(['../modules/*', '!../modules/*-ie.styl'])
```

Or, is there a way to write it the regexp way, similar to:

```
import('../modules/+(*|!*-ie.*)')
```

Answer (score 2):

If what you are asking for is a regex to match files that don't contain a `-ie.style` then this should do the trick:

```
^(.(?!-ie\.style))+$
```

Comment: Thank you for that regex! Still, I can not find a way to apply it to import, like this: 'import('../modules/**/^(.(?!-ie\.style))+$)'